# Default number of Workers and Schedulers in AWS Managed Workflow for Apache Airflow(MWAA) service

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

The AWS MWAA provides 3 types of Environment classes : mw1.small, mw1.medium and mw1.large
The pricing details are available in this link : https://aws.amazon.com/managed-workflows-for-apache-airflow/pricing/

I want to know what is the default no of Workers and Schedulers for each of the environmental class.

In the Pricing Example(in the above link), it is mentioned that for a Medium environment 1 worker and 2 schedulers are included with the environment.